# Web development scheme for staging and production servers using Git Push

Tags: mysql, git

I am using git to manage a dynamic website (PHP + MySQL) and I want to send my files from my *localhost* to my *staging* and *development* servers in the most efficient and hassle-free way.

I am currently convinced that the best way for me to approach this problem is to use [this git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to organize my local git repo.  From there, I will use the **release** branches to `push` to my *staging server* for testing.  Once I am happy that the **release** code works on the *staging server*, I can then `merge` with my **master** branch and `push` that to my *production server*.

#### Pushing to *Staging Server*:

As noted in many [introductory git post](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/01/push-to-only-bare-repositories.html)s, I could run into problems `push`ing into a `non-bare` repo, so, as suggested in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging/3838804#3838804), I plan to `push` the **release** branch to a `bare` repo on the server and have a post-receive hook that `clone`s the `bare` repo to a `non-bare` repo that also acts as the web-hosted directory.

#### Pushing to *Production Server*:

Here's my newest source of confusion...

In the response that I cited above, it made me curious as to why @Paul states that it's a completely different story when `push`ing to a live, *development server*.  I guess I don't see the problem.  Would it be safe and hassle-free to follow the same steps as above, but for the **master** branch?  Where are the potential pit-falls?

#### Config Files:

With respect to configuration files that are unique to each environment (`.htaccess`, `config.php`, etc), it seems simplest to `.gitignore` each of those files in their respective repos on their respective servers.  Can you see anything immediately wrong with this?  Better solutions?

#### Accessing Data:

Finally, as I initially stated, the site uses MySQL databases to store data.  How would you suggest I access that data (for testing purposes) from the *staging server* and *localhost*?

I realize that I may have asked way too many questions for a single post, but since they're all related to the best way to set up this development scheme, I thought it was necessary.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use you source code control system for managing this kind of task?
Pushing files around is (kinda) easy, and there are alternatives like Rsync which do this very effectively. The questions around config files and databases are what you should be concentrating on for a non-trivial web app, because that's where it often goes wrong. You absolutely must keep those under source code control, and you need a predictable, repeatable mechanism for keeping them up to date on each server/environment.

Comment: @NevilleK It seems like Mark's answer below is thinking along the same lines that I was.  However, I'm open to considering your suggestions if you feel like expanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Pushing to the production server

I assume that in the [response you quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838727/git-post-receive-hook-for-website-staging/3838804#3838804), the answer refers to pushing to the production server as "a different story", just because one can push any old commit to the staging server for testing, but you would be very careful only to push a thoroughly tested version to the production server.

I think the approach you refer to (of deploying by pushing to a bare repository with a `post-receive` that does `git checkout -f` with an appropriately set `GIT_WORK_TREE`) is a good one for deploying from git.

#### Config Files

That is a reasonable plan, but you have to be a somewhat careful about using `.gitignore` to ignore configuration files - you might want to look at this answer for more about this:

- [How can I have different versions of a file in the local working directory, remote working directory and git ftp target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174190/how-can-i-have-different-versions-of-a-file-in-the-local-working-directory-remo/7174985#7174985)

#### Accessing data

I think the question about data for your staging server really is a separate issue, since none of that data will be in your version control system - it might be worth adding another question here about that issue.  You *could* have a script that dumps data on your live server and imports it to the staging server, but I can think of many situations in which that would be undesirable, particularly where customer details and data protections laws have to be considered.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Wrt Accessing Data, I was expecting that you would suggest I ask it as a separate question...  The only reason that I thought it may be related to this version control scheme is because I thought it may be possible to set up different config files to access the data from the production server from the various servers - or something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/articles/g/i/t/GitFaq_ebc3.html) reccomends [this](http://utsl.gen.nz/git/post-update) post-receive hook script to reset the head of a non-bare repository after it is pushed to. It will save any changes that are uncommitted on the remote using a stash. Personally, I'd rather it reject the push in that case, but that can be cone

(please note: Lots of answers contain out of date links to the FAQ and the script - hopefully these will remain valid for some time at least)

Answer (score 0):

I use git flow too.  For config files in expressionengine, we use [ee master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) which basically determines the environment its in and applied a specific config.  I imagine it could easily be modified for whatever you're doing.

For deployments, we use [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) which allows you to add "[deploy:Environment]" to a commit message, which will make it upload (ftp) your specified branch (the one you commit to) to the specified environment, which you configure in their web interface, when you git push.

I've been trying to find an effective solution for .htaccess files that will allow me to htpasswd one of my environments, but not all.  It looks like it's possible in Apache 2.3 with something like this:

```
<if "%{HTTP_HOST} == 'dev.example.com'">
    # auth directives
</if>
```

but sadly, most of the production servers we use are running an earlier version, which doesn't support the  directive :(