# Accessing MySQL data on Production Server from Staging Server and Localhost for Code Testing

Tags: mysql, git, sphinx

If I have a development scheme set up as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180826/web-development-scheme-for-staging-and-production-servers-using-git-push), how would you suggest I access data that is stored on the *production server* from the *staging server* and from *localhost* for code testing purposes?

The data consists of a MySQL database that contains many tables of **course** information data (like a list of courses) that are searchable via Sphinx Search.

I don't want to have to reindex and configure Sphinx and my database elements on the *localhost* and *staging server* each time a new course is added to the *production server*, so any suggestions are welcome.

Also, I know there are a few *similar* questions out there, but none that I have found that address using MySQL data with Sphinx Search and Git — assuming those elements of the question change the potential solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So are looking for a way to push down production data into your staging and development environments?

If so, I wouldn't recommend having your staging environments and localhost environments access your production database directly... that seems like you'd run the risk of those activities impacting your production environment.

Instead, I'd recommend taking a production backup, scrubbing any sensitive information out of it, and then restore that database into your staging and development environments.